# Is it a bad idea to use the default keyword when initializing member variables?

Tags: c#

Historically speaking, I have initialized member variables prior to assignment like so:

```
private bool _myBool = false;
private int _myInt = int.MinValue;
private string _myString = String.Empty;
```

Lately I've found myself initializing them like so (normally with primitives):

```
private DateTime _myDateTime = default(DateTime);
private bool _myBool = default(bool);
//etc
```

Is this a bad or good practice?  How come?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really see a point in doing so, since you're adding extra code that really does nothing.

Same would apply if you were trying to default(class), you'd get null.

Comment: it does, however, make the default value explicit in the code.  And it would prevent the "use of uninitialized variable" error.

Comment: @Tony, it could actually HIDE "use of uninitialized variable" errors, ie it would hide the fact that the variable wasn't being set to a meaningful value before use. That's bad.

Comment: @DavidArno: fields are always initialized by the compiler. "Use of uninitialized variable" can only happen to a local.

Comment: @TonyVitabile There's no "use of uninitialized value" errors in any of these, because these are all fields, not locals.

Comment: @John, it's bad practice to initialise variables to default values, only to override them later, regardless of whether fields or local variables.

Answer (score 3):

`private int _myInt = int.MinValue;` and `default(int)` are different.

It all depends on your requirement. If you want your variables to have a value then IMO using `default` is more readable and clear.

It only matters to variables local to your function, for class fields it would be done by the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Adding statements directing the compiler to do what it is going to do anyway is a bad practice (that applies to `bool _myBool = false` as well, albeit to a lesser degree).

Unlike locals that must be assigned explicitly, fields are implicitly initialized to their defaults. The compiler already knows to do that, so the additional code is definitely *not* for the compiler.

Since the only other "consumers" of your code are your readers, the question boils down to "is is reasonable to expect a reader to know that fields in a class are initialized to their default values?" I think the answer should be "yes", because this is extremely basic knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

There is no value in initializing fields to `default(T)`, since that is done by the compiler "by default".

There is even less value in initializing any variable if that variable will always be set before it is used:

```
public void Foo(){
    DataSet ds = null;
    ds = new DataSet();
}
```

Why clear it before you set it?

Answer (score 1):

In the sense that it increases the cognitive load on readers of your code, this is a practice many would view as being detrimental. If I see an initialization, I expect it to provide some real meaning. The main use of the `default` keyword is with generics.